# Higher order Tensor elements summation

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, linear-algebra, tensor

I have a $D$-way tensor $H$ of dimension $I \times I \times \dots \times I$ ($D$ times), that represent the coefficients of a polynomial. For better understanding, please refer to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718760/higher-order-tensor-computations

I am trying to sum the elements in a position in H and all possible unique permutations of this positional index and rearranging them in a vector $F$. The vector $F$ first contains the coefficients of 2nd order monomial, followed by 3rd order and so on. How can I extend this code for any higher order polynomials without having to write many nested for loops?

I am looking for possible ways to make the below code work for any given $Order$. For now, the code works for $Order = 5$. For higher order, I have to add more nested for loops. But this is not an optimal solution.

```
pos = 1; start = 2; Memory = 3; Order = 3; I = Memory+2; H = randn(I*ones(1,Order));
F = zeros(1,1000);

if Memory > 0
    if Order > 1
        for i = start:I
            for j = i:I
                indices = num2cell(unique(perms([j,i,ones(1,Order-2)]),'rows'));
                [F,pos] = calcF(indices,F,pos,H);
            end
        end
    end
    if Order > 2
        for k = start:I
            for i = k:I
                for j = i:I
                    indices = num2cell(unique(perms([j,i,k,ones(1,Order-3)]),'rows'));
                    [F,pos] = calcF(indices,F,pos,H);
                end
            end
        end
    end
    if Order > 3
        for m = start:I
            for k = m:I
                for i = k:I
                    for j = i:I
                        indices = num2cell(unique(perms([j,i,k,m,ones(1,Order-4)]),'rows'));
                        [F,pos] = calcF(indices,F,pos,H);
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    if Order > 4
        for n = start:I
            for m = n:I
                for k = m:I
                    for i = k:I
                        for j = i:I
                            indices = num2cell(unique(perms([j,i,k,m,n,ones(1,Order-5)]),'rows'));
                            [F,pos] = calcF(indices,F,pos,H);
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end

function [F,pos] = calcF(indices,F,pos,H)
    for l = 1:size(indices,1)
        F(pos) = F(pos) + H(indices{l,:});
    end
    pos = pos + 1;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indices of the nested loops can be pre-computed. If the form of the nested loops were as `for j = i+1:I` [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) could be used to generate the indices. So the function `generate_index` is provided to compute those indices:

```
for ord = 2:Order
    idx = generate_index (start:I, ord);
    for c = 1: size(idx, 1)
        indices = num2cell(unique(perms([idx(c, :), ones(1,Order-ord)]),'rows'));
        [F,pos] = calcF(indices,F,pos,H);
    end
end


function out = generate_index (N, k)
    v = (1:numel(N)).';
    bl = true;
    for i = 1:k-1
        vtmp = reshape(v, [repmat(1,1,i) numel(v)]);
        bl = bl & (v <= vtmp);
        v = vtmp;
    end
    c = cell (1, k);
    [c{:}] = ind2sub(repmat(numel(N), 1, k), find(bl));
    idx = [c{:}];
    out = N(idx);
end
```

Note that if `(v <= vtmp)` is changed to `(v < vtmp)` the output will be the same as `nchoosek`.

Comment: Thank you, @rahnema1. This strategy is correct, except that the elements in final vector F are rearranged in the order that is not desired. You can observe the deviation between my manual code and your code. This comes from the line ````ind2sub(repmat(numel(N), 1, k), find(bl))````. The order in which linear indices change to subscripts are jumbled, and this reflects in the final F vector. so I changed ````bl = bl & (v <= vtmp);```` to ````bl = bl & (v >= vtmp);````